# I have a problem with displaying the data inside the sheet

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am trying to display a link from the variable

```
@StateObject var modelNew = Api()
```

But I want to take a value in the sheet

Inside the view, I can view the entire content without a problem

```
struct detiles2: View {

var model : model
@State var isPlayer = false

@StateObject var modelNew = Api()

var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        let link = URL(string: APIgetURL.PathImage + (model.image_path ?? ""))
            URLImage(link!) { image in
                image
                    .resizable()
                    .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.2), radius: 10, x: 20, y: 20)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 200)
            }
            
        Text("Hello").padding()
        
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                ForEach(modelNew.models) { item in
                    HStack {
                        
                            ZStack {
                                
                            Circle()
                            .frame(maxWidth: 30, maxHeight: 30)
                            .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.2), radius: 10, x: 20, y: 20)
                              
                                Image(systemName: "play.fill")
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        isPlayer.toggle()
                                    }
                            }.padding(.leading, 15)
                            
                            
                            Spacer()
                            VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 15) {
                                Text(item.title)
                                Text(item.algiment).font(.footnote).foregroundColor(Color.brown)
                            }.padding(.trailing, 5)
                        let link = URL(string: APIgetURL.PathImage + (model.image_path ?? ""))
                            URLImage(link!) { image in
                                image
                                    .resizable()
                                    .cornerRadius(20)
                                    .frame(maxWidth: 80, maxHeight: 80)
                            }
                    }.padding(.trailing, 5)
                }
            }
        }
        
        Spacer()
    }
    .onAppear() {
        modelNew.getData(url: model.url!)
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $isPlayer) {
            
            player(url: <String>) //Here ----- I want to pull it out like right away ForEach(modelNew.models) { item in} To get item.url
    }
    .ignoresSafeArea()
}
}
```

Here I am fetching new data and it was displayed correctly in the view, but inside the sheet I was not able to do so

```
class Api : ObservableObject{

@Published var models : [model] = []

func getData (url : String) {
    
    guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    let token = "38|xxxxx"
    
    request.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, responce, err in
        
        guard let data = data else { return }
        
        print(data)
        do {
            let dataModel = try JSONDecoder().decode([model].self, from: data)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.models = dataModel
            }
        } catch {
            print("error: ", error)
        }
    }
    .resume()
}
}
```

Comment: Try passing in your data from the first view into the sheet. Also, could you please post the code for the actual sheet?

Answer (score 1):

you could try a different approach using `.sheet(item:...)` as in
this sample code, to show your sheet with the video player. You should be able to adapt this code to suit your purpose. Works for me.

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import AVKit
import SwiftUI

struct SiteURL: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var urlString: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var sheetUrl: SiteURL?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("show player sheet", action: {
            sheetUrl = SiteURL(urlString: "https://jplayer.org/video/m4v/Finding_Nemo_Teaser.m4v")
        })
        .sheet(item: $sheetUrl) { site in
            if let url = URL(string: site.urlString) {
                VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: url))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, in your `.onTapGesture {...}` set the `sheetUrl` with your `item` info, like in the sample code `Button`,
instead of `isPlayer.toggle()`.

EDIT-1: here is another example code to show that my answer with `.sheet(item:...)` works.

```
struct Model: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id = UUID()
    var image_path: String
    var title: String
    var algiment: String
    var url: String
}

class Api: ObservableObject {
    // for testing
    @Published var models: [Model] = [
        Model(image_path: "image_path-1", title: "Finding_Nemo_Teaser", algiment: "model algiment-1", url: "https://jplayer.org/video/m4v/Finding_Nemo_Teaser.m4v"),
        Model(image_path: "image_path-2", title: "Incredibles_Teaser", algiment: "model algiment-2", url: "https://jplayer.org/video/m4v/Incredibles_Teaser.m4v")]
    
    func getData(url: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        let token = "38|xxxxx"
        request.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, responce, err in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            print(data)
            do {
                let dataModel = try JSONDecoder().decode([Model].self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.models = dataModel
                }
            } catch {
                print("error: ", error)
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    
    @State var videoUrl: SiteURL?  // <-- here
    
    // var model : model
    @StateObject var modelNew = Api()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            //            let link = URL(string: "https://ccc/" + (model.image_path ?? ""))
            //            URLImage(link!) { image in
            //                image
            //                    .resizable()
            //                    .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.2), radius: 10, x: 20, y: 20)
            //                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 200)
            //            }
            Text("Hello").padding()
            VStack {
                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                    ForEach(modelNew.models) { item in
                        HStack {
                            ZStack {
                                Circle()
                                    .frame(maxWidth: 30, maxHeight: 30)
                                    .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.2), radius: 10, x: 20, y: 20)
                                
                                Image(systemName: "play.fill")
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        videoUrl = SiteURL(urlString: item.url) // <-- here
                                    }
                            }.padding(.leading, 15)
                            Spacer()
                            VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 15) {
                                Text(item.title)
                                Text(item.algiment).font(.footnote).foregroundColor(Color.brown)
                            }.padding(.trailing, 5)
                            //  let link = URL(string: APIgetURL.PathImage + (model.image_path ?? ""))
                            //                            URLImage(link!) { image in
                            //                                image
                            //                                    .resizable()
                            //                                    .cornerRadius(20)
                            //                                    .frame(maxWidth: 80, maxHeight: 80)
                            //                            }
                        }.padding(.trailing, 5)
                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .onAppear() {
            // modelNew.getData(url: model.url!)
        }
        .sheet(item: $videoUrl) { site in    // <-- here
            if let url = URL(string: site.urlString) {
                VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: url))
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

Comment: This needs a [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). When you show partial code like this, you get educated guesses as answers.

Comment: I am fetching data from the API, which I am fetching from is the class like this -- **@StateObject var modelNew = Api()** -- I can't do your method Secondly I can't put the line inside the button because I use a Codable inside the model does not accept your method

Comment: I don't understand your comments: `I can't do your method` and `...can't put the line inside the button because I use a Codable...`

The idea with this example code is to use `.sheet(item:...)`. 
I suggest you do the tutorial at: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/  
and read-up on how to use `.sheet(item:...)` at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:).  As I said in my answer, adapt the code, 
use  `.sheet(item:...)`  and modify `.onTapGesture {...}`.

Comment: updated my answer with **more** example code. Is this working for you? If not, what error do you get, on what line.

Comment: did my answer not work for you?